# .NET method invocation interception

Tags: .net, language-agnostic

I need to intercept method invocations... please suggest a ready-made solution.
It's necessary to block access to some methods (so calling them will generate an exception)

Comment: How to ask questions - http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: What's the context here? Is this about mocking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) offers the functionality you a looking for. For a full AOP solution you can use [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net).

Since you are just searching for a way to intercept method calls, you just need a subset of AOP. So any [IoC container](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx) which offers interface interception is also suitable. To my knowledge [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/), [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) and [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html) offers interface interception.

**Edit**: If you need interception really fast and have an existing code base, I suggest to use PostSharp. In order to use some IoC container you maybe need to modify a lot of code. If you have a new project consider IoC. Designing an application using IoC has a lot of positive effects.

Answer (score 2):

Aspect Orientated Programming facilitates this sort of task. There are many framworks to use, I've used Spring.Net which is pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

[Using Interception with Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff646991.aspx).

There's your ready-made solution, part of the Microsoft Enterprise Library.

Answer (score 1):

for AOP could suggest this one [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html)

Or even the built-in [`RealProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy.aspx) class (requires that your class inherits `MarshalByRefObject`)